# Hide/Unhide Controls using combobox in WPF windows

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

i want to hide and unhide some labels and a textbox using combobox. The textbox is populated from database using datasource. I have tried the code but the application is not giving any response.

Code:

```
private void _cmbRole_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_cmbRole.SelectedValue == "3")
            {
                _txtPmdc.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                _lblAffiliation.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                _lblPmdb.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }

            else
            {
                _txtPmdc.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                _lblAffiliation.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                _lblPmdb.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            }
        }
```

xaml:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="_cmbRole" Grid.Column="2" DisplayMemberPath="type" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="10,14,52,10" Grid.Row="1" SelectedValuePath="role_id" FontSize="14" SelectionChanged="_cmbRole_SelectionChanged">
                        <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
                    </ComboBox>
```

Comment: Is your method getting called?

Comment: oh! let me put a breakpoint and debug it! Good Point

Comment: @PraveenPaulose...yes it is called and on every selection it jumps to else clause

Comment: In your debugger, what is the value of _cmbRole.SelectedValue?

Comment: what is the binding source to this combobox? can you put a breakpoint on the "if" statement line and inspect _cmbRole.Selectedvalue value when you select "3"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `SelectedValue` is not a string, so the comparison is always `false`. Try the following:

```
if (_cmbRole.SelectedValue.ToString() == "3")
```

The better way is to compare the `SelectedValue` with a value of the correct type. For example if it is an integer, you should compare it with `3`.

But you can also compare the [`SelectedIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedindex.aspx) and [`SelectedItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem.aspx) property. Possibly is that the better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are comparing the wrong data type. You are binding to Role ID which in most probability is an integer and you are comparing it with a string when you write `== "3"`

If it is an integer, you should be writing

```
if (_cmbRole.SelectedValue == 3)
{
    //true block here
}
```